# How to cast dynamic array to static array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

In c++ how do you cast a dynamic array to static?

Say

I have

```
int ** da;
da = new int*[9];
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) da[i] = new int[9];
```

and my function argument is of type 
`int[9][9]`, how do I cast da so my function can use it?

Comment: What is your function specification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `int[9][9]` is 81 integers consecutive in memory, taking `81*sizeof(int)` bytes. An `int *[9]` is a sequence of 9 pointers to integer, taking `9*sizeof(int *)` bytes. Each of these are setup to point to 9 distinct sequences of 9 ints.

You cannot use one in place of the other - no casting will change that these two are laid out completely different in memory.

Answer (score 1):

you don't - you must move as necessary if function keeps its signature. example:

```
void function(int a[9][9]);

int tmp[9][9];

// move to temp
for (size_t i(0); i < 9; ++i) {
    for (size_t j(0); j < 9; ++j) {
        tmp[i][j] = da[i][j];
    }
}

function(tmp);

// move to da
for (size_t i(0); i < 9; ++i) {
    for (size_t j(0); j < 9; ++j) {
        da[i][j] = tmp[i][j];
    }
}
```

the reason: the layout and alignment of 2D arrays is explicitly defined, and implementation defined. the function's implementation expects the exact layout and alignment. any other layout would obviously introduce a bug.

even `int tmp[9*9]` is not guaranteed to be the same as `int tmp[9][9]`.

fortunately, creating this on the stack and copying to/from is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

It may not relate to this question. But it reminds me a trick in matrix using C. The good part is we only need to call malloc and free once. The bad part is.....

```
// create the buffer and assign the pointer array
int  i, j;
int* buffer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 81);

int* matrix[9]; // 9 * 9
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    matrix[i] = buffer + i * 9;

// assign some value using matrix[i][j]
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        matrix[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);

// retrieve the value in matrix
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;

// free the buffer
free(buffer);
```